# Capturing specific error instead of arcpy.ExecutionError?

Tags: arcpy

How can I specify this script to capture specifically the error 001566, instead of the current general execution error?

> Error 001566:Failed to create raster dataset. The reason could be: The
>   clip feature is outside the raster extent

```
try:
    arcpy.Clip_management(lyr,rectangle='#',out_raster=out_feature, in_template_dataset = clip_feature, nodata_value="256", clipping_geometry="ClippingGeometry", maintain_clipping_extent="NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
except arcpy.ExecutionError:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always going to raise an ExcecutionError, but one strategy could be to check the error string itself.  For example:

```
try:
    arcpy.Clip_management([...])
except arcpy.ExecutionError as e:
    if 'Error 001566' not in str(e):
        raise  # re-raise the exception if it's not the error we're expecting
    # handle the error here
```